# LINQ2SQL:Calling Stored procedure and reading return value

Tags: linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

Using LINQ 2SQL , How can i call a stored procedure which returns either 1 or 0 when being executed.My procedure has 3 input params.I want to know the return value from procedure in my code too.

Comment: How exactly do you want to use LINQ to SQL for this? You can add a method to the partial DataContext that calls this SP using old fashion ADO.NET calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you drag the SProc from the Server Explorer into the Linq2Sql builder, it will create a method in the DataContext that returns a collection of an object created to match the results of your SProc, containing the result.